# LINQ TO SQL query to match csv field to the another table field

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the below tables

```
**MemberMst**
MemberID Name      Hobbies
1        Ronak     1,3,4
2        Kapil     2,4

**HobbiesMst**
HobbyId   Title
1         Computer Game
2         Cricket
3         Skating
4         Basket Ball
```

Hobbies in Member master is the value from the HobbiesMst. Now i want the hobbies of the member from HobbiesMst. using linq query. i try Split, Contains, SelectMany but failed to compile.

So im confused how to do Many to Many relation in this situation.

```
i want below output.
==============================================
MemberId Name     Title
1        Ronak    Computer Game
1        Ronak    Skating
1        Ronak    Basket Ball
2        Kapil    Cricket
2        Kapil    Basket Ball
```

Comment: So you have 3 tables , right ? if yes , tell what output do you exacly want

Comment: No i don't have three tables, i just have two tables and i want join this two tables but i have multiple values on both the side.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a many to many relationship between two tables you should create a third table to handle the relationship . in your case the schema whould be like this :

```
    MemberMst                 Member_Hobbie                 HobbiesMst
MemberId   Name           Id   MemberId   HobbiId         HobbyId   Title
```

Each record in the Member_Hobbies table shows a specific hobbie of a specific member .

Comment: i appreciate your view but its not possible now. because im upgrading the old system. is there any option to achieve this in LINQ i allready done in sql.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
var result = from record in 
                (
                    from transform in MemberMst.AsEnumerable( )
                    select new
                    {
                        MemberId = transform.MemberId,
                        Name = transform.Name,
                        Hobbies = transform.Hobbies
                                           .Split( new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries )
                                           .Select( item => Convert.ToInt32( item ) )
                                           .ToList( )

                    }
                )
             from hobby in HobbiesMst
             where record.Hobbies.Contains( hobby.HobbyId )
             select new 
             {
                record.MemberId,
                record.Name,
                hobby.Title
             };
```

Sadly i'm not sure if this even works. But you could try to convert your csv-field in the client and not on the sql-server.

The inner-query will be executed first and loads **every** record from the table into your client. Then it tries to transform your csv-field into a `List<int>` values (which can even throw a exception when the data cannot be converted). Then it performs a join against the `HobbiesMst` table. All in all not a very good solution.

I would recommend a many-to-many relation-table instead (like Karamafrooz).

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you are on the right track, the following should compile...

```
var query = MemberMst.SelectMany(
                mem => HobbyMst.Where(hob => mem.Contains(hob.HobbyId)),
                (mem,hob) => new 
                {
                 MemberId = mem.MemberId, 
                 Name = mem.Name, 
                 Title = hob.Title
                })
```